# Unable to launch x11vnc before login on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

I was following this guideline regarding Continuously running x11vnc on my Kubuntu 16.04.
I found Xsetup in here /etc/sddm/Xsetup and I added there:

```
 /usr/local/bin/x11vnc -rfbauth /path/to/the/vnc/passwd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -forever -bg
```

x11vnc is started correctly and I can see it in process list AFTER I login as some user. I'd like for it to be working BEFORE I log into Linux.

I found some solutions on Stack Overflow however they are not relevant to Kubuntu 16.04

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem on Kubuntu 16.04 adding into /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup 
the following line:

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -rfbauth [YOUR X11VNC PASSWORD FILE LOCATION]  -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -forever -bg
```

Before that I generated password using:

```
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd
```

This allows to launch x11vnc process as root even at Kubuntu login screen.

Comment: Tested today: it also works on ubuntu 18.04 login screen

Answer (score 2):

So aparently 16.04 has a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1566542) related to sddm that make the x11vnc's `-auth guess` (which I think is happening by default in your example) logic to fail. The solution is to add `-auth /var/run/sddm/* -display :0` to your command line, which I have had success with.

Answer (score 0):

To run a script at startup of Kubuntu, before login, you would edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your desired commands.

Make sure that the script ends with `exit 0`.

For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/x11vnc -rfbauth /path/to/the/vnc/passwd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -forever -bg
exit 0
```